# What does perform better on mobile? Head.js or one big js file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, loading

I was reading the theory section on the head.js homepage (http://headjs.com/) And I agree that loading scripts in parallel performs better. But there must be a limit?

- I usually have a LOT of js files. I like my application to be very modular and most scripts are between 1 and 3KB. That seems like a lot of http requests and would kill the benefit a loding scripts in parallel. I wonder if anyone made some kind of measurement to see what is the threshold where using a loader such as head.js make sense, and where it is better to just have a big js file? (all files being equally minified)
- My other concern is on 4G connected devices. We knoe that the overhead for HTTP request is greater on 4G networks. Does a solution like head.js (or require.js, or lab.js,...) still make sense in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I currently develop HeadJS

1st thing 1st, the theory section on the site is quite old, the waterfall screenshot you see is like FF3 or 4 ..navigators have come a very long way since then :)

It's true that parallel loading is the best thing, but secret is, almost all navigators do it today all by themselves behind the scenes [BrowserScope Stats](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top-m)

My suggestion to you:

- Minify your js
- Make a big bundle
- Stick it in the bottom of your page

Now do what it takes to make your product work without having a single script in your <head>, maybe 1 script .. something that allows you to push functions to the end of the page using .ready(function)

Strive to have a UI layout that works via CSS (like bootstrap or other), not JS (jQuery Mobile or other).

If you do need to push some functions to the end of the page, then HeadJS can help you as it has .ready() built in. You should still strive to have ALL your scripts except HeadJS at the bottom of you page.

Once in the bottom of the page, include your scripts via the script tag (preferred method), or if you need dynamic dependency management, use .js() to load scripts in parallel.

Well, there are other things to consider, but the above will already go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: link is to resource written by me.

Use RequireJS or any other AMD loader. So that you can load resources selectively or on demand. You may structure your applcation that way so that you minimize resources that are required initially, and load the rest asynchronously later. Check:  **[Understanding AMD & RequireJS](http://www.devbridge.com/articles/understanding-amd-requirejs)**.